# Can a Complication access Healthkit when the watch screen is off?

Tags: swift, watchkit, core-motion, watchos-2, healthkit

If the watch screen is off and the periodic Complication reload happens, can HealthKit be accessed? What about CMPedometer?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, data from both frameworks should be accessible by complications during periodic updates.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe...

HealthKit is secure data, and cannot be accessed if a device is locked.

However, for the Watch, in my testing, HealthKit is available in cases where:

1. The watch is worn on the wrist
2. The watch is set to unlock with unlocking of the phone (wrist detection is on.)
3. You unlock the phone.

So, basically, if you unlock the phone and the watch unlocks, it can remain unlocked on your wrist and allow HealthKit access until it locks again.

If the watch is locked, HealthKit data will not be available.